# chunking and limit in fputcsv

Tags: laravel, fputcsv

i am trying to export user details using fputcsv in laravel..this is my code.

```
     DB::table('users')->where('department', '=', MCA)->distinct('email')->select('rollno', 'email')
                    ->chunk(500, function ($users) use ($handle) {
                        foreach ($users as $user) {
                            // Add a new row with data
                            fputcsv($handle, [
                                $user->rollno,
                                $user->email,

                            ]);
                        }
  });

            fclose($handle);
        }, 200, $headers);

        return $response->send();
```

using this code i am able to get all the records but is there any option to limit no of records to be exported.i have tried using take() but it didnt work.
any suggestions?

Comment: isn't this already chunking them by 500?

Comment: @CanCelik ya its chunking then by 500 but my problem this query would generate 10000 record but i want to get only 3000.

Comment: Have you tried doing the take first and then chunk?

Comment: @CanCelik i am trying to scale this upto a million entries. if i take first then the variable wont be able to handle this much data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use take to limit your queries.

```
DB::table('users')->where('department', '=', MCA)
                   ->distinct('email')
                   ->select('rollno', 'email')
                   ->take(3000)
                   ->chunk(500, function ($users) use ($handle) {
                       ....
                       ....
                       ....

                   });

return $response->send();
```

Comment: I have tried the same but but its not limitng..its fetching the whole result.

Comment: Not sure why if this wouldn't limit. I would try removing distinct('email') and use groupby instead. Also maybe chunking the results after the query?